# Why flapping rudder produce net thrust if one half-stroke produce thrust and second half-stroke drag?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, propulsion

In small sailing boat like optimist is well know technique when there is no wind, rudder pupming which push boat forward.You just need push-pull rudder stick left to right with fast movement.
Rudder works complety under the hull, so there is no pressure interaction between stern and rudder.

Forward half-stroke is when rudder rotate from centerline to left or right
(from 2 to 1 or from 2 to 3).

Why stiff rudder(not felxibile like flippers) produce net thrust if forward half-stroke produce drag?
(Or maybe forward half stroke produce thrust as well? I dont think so..)

Please explain your answer with pressures at rudder sides for two condition;

1. boat speed zero
2. boat is moving

Avoid Newton 3 law.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The diagram seems a little off - are you sure all those arrows are pointing in the right direction?

Comment: It would be a mistake to think the resultant force in the bottom diagram is equal to the thrust in the top diagram. The top diagram pushes water away from both the rudder and the boat. The bottom diagram pushes water from the rudder into the boat (You can't push a car while you are inside of it).

Comment: @GordonMcDonald I believe OP is trying to illustrate the forced involved in just one swing of the rudder and how just one swing can move the boat forward without the need for swinging back and forth.

Comment: @JurgenM But this is all moot after you just talked about knowing about centripetal force. How can you say that and still wonder why the boat doesn't move forward? What do you think happens when you throw water backwards? What you just said and what your diagrams indicate are contradictory. On my end, you can't assume the resultant due to the halves of the stroke are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction because the boat is in the way and that does make a difference (unless you somehow believe the boat does not feel waves from the rudder). Also an induced drag makes it point fwd as bit.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it has nothing to do with regions of higher or lower pressure (if those even exist). When you pump the rudder you are pushing water *backward* and by Newton's Third Law that water exerts an equal and opposite force on the boat, pushing it forward.

Comment: This is circular reasoning. We infer from the fact that the boat is moved that pumping the rudder has a net propulsive effect. The question is: pumping the rudder is a side-to-side motion. One would expect that the only effect will be that four each pull on the rudder the boat will pivot a little in the opposite direction. It is the counterintuitive propulsive effect that needs explanation.

Comment: @Cleonis You are pushing some water backwards, even though you are pushing a lot of the water side to side. The rudder movement isn't strictly side to side, it is circular. I imagine that if you set it up to be exactly side to side, the boat would in fact not move forwards.

Comment: @Alex Please dont explain rudder thrust with Newton 3 law,  action-reaction is too simple and dont explain how pressure around rudder produce thrust.

Comment: @Jurgen Newton's laws are "too simple" to explain the world around us? The discipline of physics is *entirely* about explaining the workings of the world with a few simple principles.

Answer (score 2):

Below the horizontal line is my original answer, submitted 5 hours ago, but there is a better explanation that I overlooked.

In a comment to another answer Gordon McDonald points out that since the rudder hinges right at the stern the rear edge of the rudder sweeps out a sector of a circle. That alone will tend to result in pushing water rearward. Most likely that effect is the main factor.

---

When the stiff rudder is moved side-to-side it creates vortices in the water. It could be that an overall effect of the side-to-side motion is to create pairs of vortices that are constantly being shed of the rudder edge.

Hypothesis:
The side-to-side motion of the (stiff) rudder tends to continuously create vortex pairs that detach from the rudder. The vortex pair extending from the rudder will tend to lag behind when the rudder is swung the other way, making the vortex pair act somewhat like a very short flipper. That would make the side-to-side motion of the rudder act as a very inefficient flipper.

Comment: I don't buy that the circular sector alone is the answer. I fully expect the non-constant speed, plus the presence of the boat body to be factors. A uniform alternating motion would otherwise move water in opposite directions in equal amounts.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that during the forward thrust portion of the stroke the skipper pushes harder and faster creating more turbulence and drag and thus more thrust. During the reverse thrust part they slow down for more laminar flow and thus less drag and less thrust. So over one cycle the net impulse is forward.

But I also guess that the actual situation is more complex and involves more fluid dynamics.

Comment: I would guess hydrodynamics.

Answer (score 0):

The key point may be that stern of the boat moves laterally. During the first half of the stroke, the force exerted on the rudder by the water is forward and to the side. The sideways component causes the boat to rotate, so that, if you were to release the tiller and allow to rudder to align itself with the flow (which means, in the inviscid approximation, no net force on the rudder) the rudder would naturally continue past center, allowing it to reach the starting position for the return stroke without generating a backward force. The rotation of the boat eventually stops—let’s say a skeg provides some lateral resistance—and now you’re ready for the return stroke having produced some forward thrust and no backward force.

Of course, you wouldn’t actually let go of the tiller for the second half of the stroke, but by mimicking the motion you’d get if you did, it seems logical that net thrust could be generated.